# Show $\frac{\cos(n\theta)-\cos(n+1)\theta)}{2-2\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin(n+1/2)\theta}{2\sin(\theta/2)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck understanding why $\frac{\cos(n\theta)-\cos(n+1)\theta)}{2-2\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin(n+1/2)\theta}{2\sin(\theta/2)}$. I have tried $2-2\cos \theta=4\sin^2(\theta/2)$ and standard trig identities to maniplate the expression but I don't get it.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos \alpha -\cos \beta=2\sin \frac{\alpha+\beta}2\:\sin \frac{\beta-\alpha}2.
$$

Comment: The form $\;-2\sin \dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2\:\sin \dfrac{\alpha-\beta}2$ is better to easily memorise it.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

put $n+1/2=m$
then

$$\cos ((n+1)t)=\cos ((n+1/2)t+t/2) $$

$$=\cos (mt)\cos (t/2)-\sin (mt)\sin (t/2) $$

and

$$\cos (nt)=\cos (mt-t/2)=$$
$$\cos (mt)\cos (t/2)+\sin (mt)\sin (t/2) $$

done.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\cos(n\theta)-\cos((n+1)\theta)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{\theta  n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}
   \theta  (n+1)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta 
   n}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \theta  (n+1)\right)$$